# Sort javascript object without changes it's key value

Tags: javascript, object

I have below type of object, I want to sort on based on sort_value of object. I tried below solution but it gives me error.

```
var data = {
        7:{
            name: 'Test1',
            city: 'Mohali',
            sort_order: -1
        },
        9:{
            name: 'Test2',
            city: 'Delhi',
            sort_order: 2
        },
        10:{
            name: 'Test3',
            city: 'Chicago',
            sort_order: 0
        }
    }
```

**I Tried this one solution**

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.sort_order) - parseFloat(b.sort_order);
});
```

**Gives me error like this**

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.sort is not a function
```

**Expected Output**

```
var Expectedop = {
        7:{
            name: 'Test1',
            city: 'Mohali',
            sort_order: -1
        },
        10:{
            name: 'Test3',
            city: 'Chicago',
            sort_order: 0
        },
        9:{
            name: 'Test2',
            city: 'Delhi',
            sort_order: 2
        }
    }
```

Comment: The properties in an object don't have an order (they can have, but you shouldn't rely on that).

Comment: [Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is an array method but you are trying to sort an object hence the error

Comment: Why is `data` an object? Add the id to the "cities" and wrap them in an array: `[ { id: 7, city: 'Mohali', ... }, { id: 10, ... }, ... ]`

Comment: Invalid output. Tryto log this output in console and can see that the order will be always 7, 9, 10

Answer (score 0):

`sort` is an in-built method available on Arrays.

What you can do is use `Object.keys(data)` which will give you array of keys (`[7,9,10]`) and sort it using the `sort` function. When you have the keys sorted in the array, you can use them to update `sort_order` in the `data` object.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys